# Replace multiple and repeated occurrences of && with <b> and %% with <i> tag

Tags: javascript, regex, html-parsing, regex-group

I'm working on a custom parsing function where i need to parse A string with 
multiple and repeated occurrences of  && with `<b>` and %% with `<i>` tag.

I tried this regular expression.

```
html = html.replace(/[&][&](.+?)[&][&]/g, '<b>$1</b>');
html = html.replace(/[%][%](.+?)[%][%]/g, '<i>$1</i>');
```

the above replace works fine for a single group i mean

"&&This&& is a &&bold string&&" to  "**this** is a **bold string**"

This gives weird results i have repeated strings

```
&&&&This&&&& is a &&bold string&&
```

to `<b>&&This</b>&& is a <b>bold String</b>`

need help in parsing the closing and opening group to replace it with proper html tags like

to `<b><b>This</b></b> is a <b>bold String</b>`

and if possible replacing it with only a single `<b>` tag

to `<b>This</b> is a <b>bold String</b>`

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to match as many `&`s in a row as possible, requiring at least two:

```js
console.log(
  '&&&&This&&&& is a &&bold string&&'
    .replace(/&{2,}(.*?)&{2,}/g, '<b>$1</b>')
);
```

Note that if you want to replace both `&`s with `<b>` tags and `%`s with `<i>` tags, you can use a single regular expression with a replacer function that accesses an object:

```js
const obj = {
  '&': 'b',
  '%': 'i'
};
console.log(
  '&&&&This&&&& is a &&bold string&& and there are italics %%here%%%'
    .replace(
      /([%&])\1+(.*?)\1{2,}/g,
      (_, char, text) => `<${obj[char]}>${text}</${obj[char]}>`
    )
);
```

If you want to require that the groups on each end be *balanced*, then rather than just capturing just one character in the group, also capture the whole substring of `&`s or `%`s, so you can backreference that entire substring later:

```js
const obj = {
  '&': 'b',
  '%': 'i'
};
console.log(
  '&&&&This&& is a &&bold string&& and there are italics %%here%%%'
    .replace(
      /(([%&])\2+)(.+?)\1/g,
      (_, _2, char, text) => `<${obj[char]}>${text}</${obj[char]}>`
    )
);
```

If sections aren't neatly nested inside other sections (like `<b>foo<i>bar</b>baz</i>`), then you'll have to use the original method of replacing `&&`s, and then going through the string again and replacing `%%`s:

```js
console.log(
  '&&&&This&& is a &&bold string&& and there are italics %%here%%%'
    .replace(/(&{2,})(.+?)\1/g, '<b>$2</b>')
    .replace(/(%{2,})(.+?)\1/g, '<i>$2</i>')
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response..This works fine if they are even groups . if the string has "'&&&&This&& is a &&bold string&& and there are italics %%here%%%'". the && should be displayed as it is like "'<b>&&This</b> is a" or &&<b>This</b>. The replacement should happen only when there are two && in the start and two in the end.

Comment: See edit, capture *another* group containing the entire repeating substring, and backreference it at the end

Comment: Thanks @CertianPerformance .Yeah this looks good ,but this gives a different result for combined groups like &&%%bold string&&%%  to  <b>%%bold string</b><i>

Comment: Guess you'll have to revert back to the original method then, because regex can't replace overlapping matches like that in one go

Comment: Yeah im trying that ,parsing and replacing a single group so that all the &&,%% are replaced.In general ,An italic and bold can be applied for a text right.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then a solution to transform:

```
&&&&This&&&& is a &&bold string&&
```

to:

```
<b><b>This</b></b> is a <b>bold String</b>
```

would be:

```js
console.log('&&&&This&&&& is a &&bold string&& '
.replace(/&&(.*?)&&/g, '<b>$1</b>'))
```

Comment: this gives <b></b>This<b></b> is a <b>bold string</b> .which is not expected @dacre-denny

Comment: This is a solution in response to this part of the OP "need help in parsing the closing and opening group to replace it with proper html tags like `<b><b>This</b></b> is a <b>bold String</b>`"